# Angular: Options object not accessible in template despite correct initialization

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular-material

I'm working on an Angular project and trying to display a calendar using the FullCalendar library. I have defined an options object in my component class and initialized it in the ngOnInit method. However, the options object is not accessible in the template, and as a result, the calendar component is not being displayed.

Here's the relevant code snippet from my component:

```
import {MAT_DIALOG_DATA, MatDialogRef} from '@angular/material/dialog';
import {Component, Inject, OnInit, ViewChild} from '@angular/core';
import dayGridPlugin from '@fullcalendar/daygrid';
import interactionPlugin, { Draggable } from '@fullcalendar/interaction';
import { FullCalendarComponent } from '@fullcalendar/angular';
import timeGridPlugin from '@fullcalendar/timegrid';
import resourceTimeGridPlugin from '@fullcalendar/resource-timegrid';
import {PluginDef} from "@fullcalendar/core/plugin-system";





@Component({
    selector: 'app-charts',
    templateUrl: './charts-dialog.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./charts-dialog.component.scss'],
})
export class ChartsDialogComponent implements OnInit {
    eventsModel: any;
    @ViewChild('fullcalendar') fullcalendar!: FullCalendarComponent;
       public calendarOptions!: { editable: boolean;
        plugins: PluginDef[];
        customButtons: {
            next: {
                text: string;
                click: () => void
            };
            prev: {
                text: string;
                click: () => void
            }
        };
        header: {
            left: string;
            center: string;
            right: string
        };
        theme: string;
        columnHeaderHtml: () => string;
        locale: string
    };


ngOninit{
        this.calendarOptions = {
            editable: true,
            customButtons: {
                prev: {
                    // this overrides the prev button
                    text: 'PREV',
                    click: () => {
                        const calendarApi = this.fullcalendar.getApi();
                        calendarApi.prev();
                        calendarApi.getDate();

                        alert('ttttt' + calendarApi.getDate());
                    },
                },
                next: {
                    // this overrides the next button
                    text: 'NEXT',
                    click: () => {
                        const calendarApi = this.fullcalendar.getApi();
                        calendarApi.next();
                    },
                },
            },
            theme: 'standart', // default view, may be bootstrap
            header: {
                left: 'prev',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'next',
            },
            columnHeaderHtml: () => {
                return '<b>Friday!</b>';
            },
            // locales: [esLocale, frLocale],
            locale: 'fr',
            // add other plugins
            plugins: [
                dayGridPlugin,
                interactionPlugin,
                timeGridPlugin,
                resourceTimeGridPlugin,
            ],
        };
```

an this is the html

```
<full-calendar
                          *ngIf="calendarOptions"
                          #fullcalendar
                          [editable]="true"
                          [events]="eventsModel"
                          [header]="calendarOptions.header"
                          [locale]="calendarOptions.locale"
                          [customButtons]="calendarOptions.customButtons"
                          (dateClick)="dateClick($event)"
                          (eventDragStop)="eventDragStop($event)"
                          [plugins]="calendarOptions.plugins"
                          (eventClick)="eventClick($event)"
                          [columnHeaderHtml]="calendarOptions.columnHeaderHtml"
                  ></full-calendar>
```

Comment: `{ editable: boolean }` -> `}` ?